# Get row number for next game

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, row, lookup

In Google Sheets, from one sheet I am trying to lookup the game info for the next game based on a game schedule that is maintained on a second sheet. The game dates and times in the schedule are maintained in separate columns as displayed below.

For example, since it's now 11:55am on 2/14, I'm looking for a function that will return row # 8 based on the schedule below.

[Game Schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRkpr.png)

Thank you!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1agemx6SU8ukJrstKpmDV6O_Y1YcZVgm0ZzEPZ5cP7Vs/edit?usp=sharing

I'm trying to dynamically populate cells B2, B3, and B4 on the Next Game sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(
  INDEX(Schedule!A3:C15, MATCH(NOW(),Schedule!A3:A15+Schedule!B3:B15,1)+1)
))
```

[image]

`MATCH` to assume that the range `A3:A16+B3:B16` is sorted in ascending order and return the largest value less than or equal to search_key `NOW()`. We're using `ARRAYFORMULA` for corect summing `A3:A16+B3:B16` as row by row. The one is added to move the pointer of `INDEX` to the line below.

[My sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vHs5nf2NRKd9qzXwEh9gba62OTvTg0VwBjwoc1c1eIs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is helpful, but I'm trying to get the row number so that from the second sheet I can reference each cell in that row, as that will give me control over how I want to display each of the values in each cell. Thank you!!

Comment: @Dan, just add `TRANSPOSE`.

Answer (score 0):

B2:

```
=TODAY()
```

B3:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(NOW(), " "),,2)
```

B4:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("Schedule!"&ADDRESS(MATCH(B2+B3, Schedule!A1:A+Schedule!B1:B, 1)+1, 3)))
```

[image]